# How to move in bootstrap a element whitin of a column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm try to do a `footer` with `bootstrap` and I need move a `span` element, this one is whitin of a `column` set up it with `col-sm-4` `class`, How do I can move this one for instance `20px` whitout affecting responsive design. Below I put a image about `footer` and the `html` structure and `css`. I appreciate any help.

[image]

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="location" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-3">
        <span>Location</span>
      </div>
      <div id="info" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-3">
        <span>Info about me</span>
      </div>
      <div id="created" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-3">
        <p>texto</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</footer>
```

css:

```
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

#location{
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
}
#info{
    background-color:  gray;
    height: 50px;
}

#created{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: 20px from top left?

Comment: I would like move Location at right.

Comment: You can add <span style="padding-left:20px;">move space 20px</span>

Comment: span{ margin-left:20px} thats what you are saying?

Comment: You can add <span style="padding-left:20px;">move space 20px</span> . Is there any thing wrong with this answer ? Did you tested it. If has responsive issues please tell me the issue. So that i can improve

Comment: @J.Shabu work well thanks you for your time. There is not issues for momento with responsive design.

Comment: @ julian salas please mark my answer as correct answer in the answers. if it is correct i think you have down voted it in answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<span style="padding-left:20px;">move space 20px</span>`

It will not affect responsiveness

Comment: @julian salas Is there any thing wrong with this answer ? Did you tested it. If has responsive issues please tell me the issue. So that i can improve the code